# SVG Tag Not Loading In Wordpress 5.5

Tags: php, css, wordpress, svg, wordpress-theming

I have updated my WordPress version to the newly 5.5. The theme SVG not showing. I do not know is latest WordPress 5.5 version support svg XML tag or deprecated in new version or newly WordPress CSS conflict with theme css. I do not know where is the problem exists but after the updated it's happened. here is website URL please check
[website link](https://toysandsport.com)

I will highly thankful for your support Thanks and Best Regards.

Comment: What SVG is missing, what does the code look like, and why did you block "right clicking"... I see SVGs on the login button etc.

Answer (score 1):

I see some errors in the console but none related to an SVG for the menu icons, and I'm not seeing broken images at a glance. It's a long shot but you might try clearing cache server side and on your machine.

Here are the console errors

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 () for:
actions.json
track.beeketing.com
beeketing.js

as well as alerts: 
howu-control.js?v=1597686534665:1 Howuku - please considering upgrade your account to a paid plan with higher pageview limit.

howu-control.js?v=1597686534665:1 Reached monthly limit, please consider upgrade Howuku plan!
```